# Typo3 7.6 How to show more than the editors database mount in the link wizard

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, backend, typo3-7.6.x, administration

My editors have only those pages in their database mount that they are responsible for. When they use the common link wizard while linking something internally they should be able to see a lot bigger page tree. Which setting gives them a different sight to the page tree while linking?

Answer (score 0):

they need a mount for the whole tree they should be able to link to.

for restricting the access to readonly you can use the access system of TYPO3 whichis similar to the unix filesystem: for each page you have an owner and a group.
Then you cen set access rights for owner, group and everyone.

In enhance to the unix filerights in TYPO3 you have the rights:

- Show page
- Edit content
- Edit page
- Delete page
- New pages

These values and rights can be set (recursively) in the BE module "Access"

For initial values you can set some page TSconfig, so pages below will get matching values:

```
TCEMAIN.permissions {
    # owner of page
    userid = 15
    # group of page
    groupid = 1
    # rights for owner
    user = 31
    # rights for group
    group = 19
    # rights for everyone
    everybody = 1
}
```

for the rights a bitmask is used:
**Note the different order to the usage in the BE!**

1 = Show page
 2 = Edit page
 4 = Delete page
 8 = New pages
16 = Edit content